# How to minify an INSERT and PRINT query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two PHP/SQL functions and I am wondering how I would minify them.  I'd like to run the 3 insert commands as a single $import rather than three, but I am not sure how to minify it.

```
$import9="INSERT into wp_postmeta (meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value) values(',','$data[37]','lower_electric_costs','$data[5]')";
$import10="INSERT into wp_postmeta (meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value) values(',','$data[37]','cheapest_green_electric','$data[6]')";
$import11="INSERT into wp_postmeta (meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value) values(',','$data[37]','contract_type','$data[11]')";
```

Its the same thing with my PRINT results - how would I minify this down?

```
mysql_query($import9) or die("mysql_error()");
print $import9."<br>";
mysql_query($import10) or die("mysql_error()");
print $import10."<br>";
mysql_query($import11) or die("mysql_error()");
print $import11."<br>";
```

I am still learning PHP/SQL and learning how to minify my code is an important part of it I think.  If someone can just how me an example of what a minified version would look like, then I can probably take it from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine it into a single query as follows:

```
$import9="
    INSERT into
        wp_postmeta
        (meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
    values
        (',','$data[37]','lower_electric_costs','$data[5]'),
        (',','$data[37]','cheapest_green_electric','$data[6]'),
        (',','$data[37]','contract_type','$data[11]')
";
```

However, you should use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` functions, as `mysql` functions are deprecated.

```
mysqli_query($import9);
```

It is also advised that you do not use INSERT queries with `mysqli_query` but rather use Prepared Statements for security reasons. You should check out [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

First, create a PDO instance.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb", "username", "password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); //Turn off prepared statement emulation too.
```

With a prepared statement, you would `prepare` your statement with the server:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    INSERT into
        wp_postmeta
        (meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
    values
        (?,?,?,?)
");
```

With an array like:

```
$values = array(
    array(',',$data[37], 'lower_electric_costs', $data[5]),
    array(',',$data[37], 'cheapest_green_electric', $data[6]),
    array(',',$data[37], 'contract_type', $data[11]),
);
```

Next, you'd issue a series of execute statements:

```
foreach ($values as $v) {
    $stmt->execute($v);
}
```

Finally, close the statement so that more statements can be executed:

```
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: using `mysqli` doesn't buy you a lot if you're still interpolating directly into your query.  **use placeholders.**

Comment: True, but he is just learning. Prepared statements were made for this exact sort of thing, though.

Comment: exactly: this is when he should be learning to use placeholders, so he's already in the habit.  do it right from the start.

Comment: Modified to include PDO and Prepared Statement overview.

Comment: Well, thats added a whole new level of confusion to my day :(

Comment: @Zach Well it boils down to if you are worried about security or not. If you don't care, then just go with that first query at the top. If you do care, then you need to learn to things right.

Comment: So mysqli is newer and more secure, but the structure and syntax are completely different?

Comment: @Zach mysqli stands for mysql improved. You can simply swap out `mysql_query` for `mysqli_query`, but if you do that with an `INSERT` SQL statement, then you aren't benefiting from the improvements. Also, don't confuse `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*` and `PDO` with `SQL`. The former are PHP interfaces for interacting with an SQL server which still only understands SQL.

Comment: I guess I need mysqli and pdo for dummies :D